# Why does the electron affinity increase become more exothermic down group 2 and group 5?

Tags: periodic-trends, electron-affinity

It is generally true that the electron affinity becomes less exothermic down a group, because of the increase in atomic radius.

There is a well-known exception that the electron affinity of Cl is more exothermic than that of F, because fluorine has a high electron density; adding electrons would be unfavorable because of the electron-electron repulsions.

In Group 2 and Group 5, this is more extreme: the electron affinity becomes *more* exothermic down the group. Why is this so?

[image]

Comment: I can tell why it's positive for Be, Mg and N, which is quite clear. I can't explain the "trend"...

Comment: There is no clear tendency anywhere. The only column where the electron affinity is regularly modified the way you say when going down the column is the first one.